# Unix script error: [: too many arguments

Tags: unix, sh

I have this code that outputs:

```
1: '[' '[' "" = "" ']'
2: script.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments
3: '[' '[' artifact1,artifact2,artifact3,artifact4,artifact5 = "" ']'
4: '[' '[' 2.14 = "" ']'
5: '[' '[' N = "" ']'
6: script.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments
```

Here is the part of the code:

```
set -x
NEW_TAG = "";
TAGS = artifact1,artifact2,artifact3,artifact4,artifact5;
VERSION = 2.14;
FIX = N;

if [ [ "$NEW_TAG" = "" ] || [ "$TAGS" = "" ] || [ "$VERSION" = "" ] || [ "$FIX" = "" ] ];
```

I have already put double quotes in the variables but still I encounter this error. What could have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: The `[` is actually an alias for the [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) command. I recommend you read the manual page for [`test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

Comment: Yes, does this mean my syntax is wrong? I just compared $string1 = empty string or NULL.

Comment: Yes; `[` is a command name, not a grouping operator.

Comment: Your variable assignments are also wrong; no spaces are allowed around the `=`: `NEW_TAG=""` (or just `NEW_TAG=`). Run your code through shellcheck.net to catch the more obvious errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is another name for the `test` command, not a grouping operator like parentheses.

Your `if` statement is equivalent to

```
if test [ "$NEW_TAG" = "" || ...
```

and `test` doesn't expect any more arguments if the first one is `[` (in this case it has no special meaning; it's just a non-enpty string).

The correct way to use multiple tests is

```
if [ "$NEW_TAG" = "" ] || [ "$TAGS" = "" ] || [ "$VERSION" = "" ] || [ "$FIX" = "" ];
```

You don't need any grouping, although if you really wanted to, you can use `{ ... }`:

```
if { [ "$NEW_TAG" = "" ] ||
     [ "$TAGS" = "" ] ||
     [ "$VERSION" = "" ] ||
     [ "$FIX" = "" ]; };
```

Note the `;` used to terminate the command list inside the `{ ... }`.

Also, it is a little shorter (with less room for error) to use the `-z` operator to check if a string is empty.

```
if [ -z "$NEW_TAG" ] || [ -z "$TAGS" ] || [ -z "$VERSION" ] || [ -z "$FIX" ]; then
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much! Actually I'm debugging this script. Thank you thank you!